# Filter array of objects by key and value contained in another object

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is a way to filter (or query) an array structured like this:

```
[   {
            'xml:id': 'Name1',
            sex: {
                '$t': 'M'
            },
            occupation: {
                n: 1,
                '$t': 'bank'
            }
        },
        {
            'xml:id': 'Name2',
            sex: {
                '$t': 'M'
            },
            occupation: {
                n: 1,
                '$t': 'writer'
            }
        }, {
            'xml:id': 'Name3',
            sex: {
                '$t': 'F'
            },
            occupation: {
                n: 1,
                '$t': 'bank'
            }
        }, {
            'xml:id': 'Name4',
            sex: {
                '$t': 'M'
            },
            occupation: {
                n: 1,
                '$t': 'writer'
            },
        }, {
            'xml:id': 'Name5',
            sex: {
                '$t': 'M'
            },
            occupation: {
                n: 1,
                '$t': 'writer'
            }
        }
    ]
```

whit a query of this type:

```
const pers_query: Query = {
  type: 'person',
  args: [
    {
      key: 'occupation',
      value: 'bank',
    },
    {
      key: 'sex',
      value: 'f',
    },
  ],
};
```

What I want is to filter the data with multiple keys and values, in this specific case I want to filter the data for all the occurrences of object that contains the key `sex` with value `f` **AND** the key `occupation` with value `bank`

the ***result*** should be something like this:

```
[
   {
        'xml:id': 'Name3',
        sex: {
            '$t': 'F'
        },
        occupation: {
            n: 1,
            '$t': 'bank'
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: It's invalid. Use https://jsonlint.com/ to check. If the exact format doesn't matter, then you probably don't mean JSON, but instead a JS Object.

Comment: There is no JSON here, it's just an array of objects.

Comment: yes, I'm so sorry I wrote JSON data because it's an extraction of an array of objects inside a JSON structure. My bad.

Comment: @RootAtKali no problem. It's a common mixup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.each`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
const input = [{    'xml:id': 'Name1',    sex: {      '$t': 'M'    },    occupation: {      n: 1,      '$t': 'bank'    }  },  {    'xml:id': 'Name2',    sex: {      '$t': 'M'    },    occupation: {      n: 1,      '$t': 'writer'    }  }, {    'xml:id': 'Name3',    sex: {      '$t': 'F'    },    occupation: {      n: 1,      '$t': 'bank'    }  }, {    'xml:id': 'Name4',    sex: {      '$t': 'M'    },    occupation: {      n: 1,      '$t': 'writer'    },  }, {    'xml:id': 'Name5',    sex: {      '$t': 'M'    },    occupation: {      n: 1,      '$t': 'writer'    }  }]
const pers_query = {
  type: 'person',
  args: [{
      key: 'occupation',
      value: 'bank',
    },
    {
      key: 'sex',
      value: 'f',
    },
  ],
};

const output = input.filter(person => {
  return pers_query.args.every(condition => {
    return person[condition.key]['$t'].toLowerCase() === condition.value.toLowerCase();
  });
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I looking for.

Comment: fee.l free to mark it as accepted and/or upvote as you see fit

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterData(data,query,caseSensitive=false) {
    let filteredData = data;
    // no use for type since it's  not in data
    query.args.forEach(arg => filteredData = filteredData.filter(item => caseSensitive ? item[arg.key]['$t'] === arg.value : item[arg.key]['$t'].toLowerCase() === arg.value.toLowerCase())); // you can use .lowe

    return filteredData;
}
```

This is one way to do it, note that we assign filteredData with data at beginning since where applying filter and that won't cause any change to the original array.